# Attempting to recover CentOS7 server. Mounting partition taking a long time

Tags: centos, redhat, centos7, rhel7

I have a CentOS 7 server that I am attempting to recover. I've got the install disk in the CD drive and am able to make it into the recovery process.

Once I make it into the recovery process I select the first option to mount the disc under /mnt/sysimage. However I get several thousand lines of = characters, and then the process eventually freezes and I have to restart the process all over again.

I know that there is a lot of data on this drive, does this process just take a long time to mount the drive? I don't get any errors while attempting the mount the drive, it just seems to freeze and stop doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Skip** mounting sysimage. On the console, do recovery steps.

For example, image the volume to a new, working block device. Check for I/O errors logged, possibly due to failing storage.  `fsck` or `xfs_repair` the copy.

Comment: So the reason I need to mount the sysimage is that I need to reset the root password before I can do anything with the file system.

Comment: Mounting automatically does no good if it hangs due to I/O errors or similar. Skipping mounting allows you to do recovery steps manually.